# How to retrieve data from dynamic ObjectSet in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I created one Action Filter which logs the CUD (Create, Update, Delete) operations performed by user at specific time. Using Entity Framework DB First as the Data Accessing method.

I am passing the ObjectSet to the Action Filter as string so I can retrieve the previous values of the table under CUD operation.

Inside the Action Filter I am trying to obtain the data of the ObjectSet as

> var tableSet =
>   dbContext.GetType().GetProperty(_tableName).GetValue(dbContext, null)
>   as ObjectQuery;

The following is the result I am able to see

[image: Debugging the tableSet object]

My question is, how can I get the Data that is shown in the **Results View**.

Comment: You have the type commented out, so its difficult to help.

Comment: Can't you add a generic type parameter somewhere? This is going to take tons of reflection. If it's not strong typed at compile time it never will be.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var result in tableSet){
   // do something with result
}
```

Comment: Hi Charlie. Thanks for this. But result is type 'object' and doesn't has any select method.